# Order of Convergence of a Fixed Point Iteration

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to find the order of convergence of the fixed point iteration $p_{n+1} = g(p_n)$ for $n \geq 0 $ where $g(x) = (3+x-3x^2)^{1/4}$ and the point of convergence is at $x = p$

This is how I started solving the problem.
$$
p - p_{n+1} = p - (3+p_n - 3p_{n}^2)^{1/4}
$$
Since $\epsilon_{n} = p - p_n$,

$$
\epsilon_{n+1} = p-(3+p_n - 3p_{n}^2)^{1/4}
$$
After some algebraic manipulation, I've reached (unless my math is way off),
$$
-2p\epsilon_{n+1} +\epsilon_{n+1}^2 = 3 +p -3p^2 + (4p-1)\epsilon_n-2\epsilon_n^2
$$
I'm not sure how to move on from here.

Comment: Something is wrong here. $p$ must be equal to $1$. As $\epsilon_n \to 0$, the LHS tends to $0$ while the RHS tends to $3+p-3p^2 = 1$.

Comment: You subtract $p_{n+1}=g(p_n)$ and $p=g(p)$ to get $ϵ_{n+1}=g'(c_n)ϵ_n$ with some midpoint $c_n$, and thus have to find bounds for the derivative.

Comment: @NN2 Yes, you're correct. I've forgotten to mention that.